# OData ASPNetCore CamelCase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I am struggling to find documentation on camelCase feature  for .net 6 vs 8.0.6 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData

https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/13#issuecomment-1013384492

The issue is when you query directly it's fine.

[image]

But when you use any functionality it breaks

[image: image.png]

Any ideas?

Code for Config in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddOData(options =>
{
 options.Select().Filter().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(100).OrderBy();

});
```

Code for Endpoint

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Warehouse>> Warehouses()
    {
        return _context.Warehouses;
    }
```

Tired

```
static IEdmModel GetModel()
{ 
var builder1 = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder1.EnableLowerCamelCase();
builder1.EntitySet<Warehouse>("warehouses");
builder1.EntitySet<Company>("companies");
return builder1.GetEdmModel();
}
   builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddOData(options =>
{
   options.Select().Filter().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(100).OrderBy();
  options.AddRouteComponents(GetModel());
});
```

Comment: What functionality are you referring to?

Comment: The closest functionality is  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.builder.odataconventionmodelbuilderextensions.enablelowercamelcase?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Until this is fix here's what I did with typescript/javascript to transform the response so that it can be mapped to swagger open api objects

```
return this.httpClient.request<any[]>('get', `${window.origin}/odata/${path}/?${odataQuery}`,
  {
    headers: this.headers
  }
).pipe(map((things) => {
  return things.map((thing) => { 
    return this.util.objectToCamel(thing);
  });
}));

  objectToCamel(thing: any): any{
const obj: any = {};
if (!thing)
  return null;
Object.keys(thing).forEach((key) => {
  if (Array.isArray(thing[key])) {
    thing[key] = (<any[]>thing[key]).map((thx) => {
      return this.objectToCamel(thx);
    });
  } else if (typeof thing[key] === "object")
    thing[key] = this.objectToCamel(thing[key])

  obj[key.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + key.substr(1)] = thing[key];
});
return obj;
```

}